# Does using GPL material in a paper make it impossible to transfer copyright to the publisher?

Tags: publications, license

I am writing a paper, and would like to use some GPL-licensed material I found on the internet; for instance, an image. The GPL requires any work using GPL content to be GPL licensed itself. To my understanding, using GPL content would make it impossible to transfer the copyright to the publisher, and therefore unacceptable for most research papers. It is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? Just quote some of it? And what type of "stuff" are you talking about? Source code or (much less likely) something else?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe graphics. I want to use the graphics in my paper

Comment: IANAL: The graphics does, to my knowledge, not inherit the copyright from the tools by which it is created. I believe there were attempts to impose tool copyright onto products generated with the tool and I am not sure what the current ruling is on that, but I am relatively confident this is not applying to GPL.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs What if the image itself is the GPL-licensed product? Image can have source code, too -- for instance, SVG images or those generated with Tikz.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Wow, that's a difficult one. Of course, you could define an algorithm for every product (even just 'pixel wise' printouts), but I suspect it would not become such a problem for GPL as it might be for some industry-protected copyright. I cannot imagine the creators of GPL having intended to get control over every *product* of a GPL software (as opposed to derivatives of the software itself). But, again, IANAL, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Moreover, you can also apply the GPL to classical image files like a PNG. Of course it’s somewhat idiotic, as many aspects become unclear and there is almost certainly a better suited license to express what the creator wants to allow to be done with their work.

Comment: The GPL is designed as a software license, not as a general-purpose license that can be applied to works such as photographs. You might want to contact the author and explain this to them, because they're probably confused or misinformed. If you're in the US, the fair use exception to copyright may make it legal for you to use such an image without having to comply with the license.

Comment: Notwithstanding some of the above comments, the GPL is merely a license for a copyrighted work. You, the author, still own the copyright and you can transfer the copyright to others. If obsessed the GPL forcibly applied to the whole document, the publisher would still own the copyright, it would just be obligated to continue to license it under the GPL or a compatible license.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni One thing is to copyright the *code* of the image (text file)  and another is to copyright the *image* (what you see). You can copyright the code and allow the use of the image, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a problem if you used GPL-licensed piece of software and decided to release your derived program in a GPL-incompatible way.

Other than this, you should be fine. The point of GPL is that if you improve the source code, then your improvements (in case you want to make them public) must also be licensed under GPL.

Certainly GPL does not "infect" your publications - you can e.g. cite a piece of code released under GPL, without any problems. (And you can write your paper on a Linux machine, thus running GPL'ed OS :-))